# bind variable does not exist oracle error + ssrs

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an "ORA01006 Bind variable does not exist  "error in the following code:

```
select TO_CHAR(Table1), Column1, column2 
from    a          
where Table1 between to_date(:beg_awd_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND
      to_date(:end_awd_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
order by column1
```

Data source = Oracle DB ,Retrieving report using SSRS.

Comment: Where do `:beg_awd_date` and `:end_awd_date` come from? These are bind variables.

Comment: Theses two parameters are coming from oracle data source for SSRS report.